# Android App renaming in the application manager tab

Tags: android

Does anyone knows how to change the name of the android app that appears in the applications manager list in android phones currently it shows up with the package name com.appname however i want it to be displayed as appname only

Answer (score 0):

Set an android:label="Name" in the application tag of your manifest

Comment: Yes.  If you want it can also be a string resource in your strings.xml, so it can be localized.